# Area 51 responses tab on recent activity not showing number

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, recent-activity, tabs

The orange-boxed number on the tabs on the Recent Activity page doesn't show on the Responses tab.

I received a response an hour and a half ago, and it shows in the Responses tab, but the orange number doesn't show on the Responses tab.  The response is included in the count on  the followed tab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recent Activity - Responses tab doesn't count comment to @User](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36071/recent-activity-responses-tab-doesnt-count-comment-to-user)

Answer (score 1):

Is the response a comment directly on one of your example questions or proposals, or is it an @Lance comment in a comment thread that you participated on? If it is the latter, this behavior is the same as in Stack Overflow. See [the report here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36071/recent-activity-responses-tab-doesnt-count-comment-to-user). If not... well, that'd be a different cause, then.

Comment: Yep, that's it, closing as dupe.